# Error in Fragment Replacing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I would like replace one `fragment` to another when click on `button`.

In `Fragment` class their is `listview`. `Listview` logic is clear but application crashed.

My code is given below.

```
package com.FragmentClasses;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.AdapterClasses.Favourite_sports_List_Adapter;
import com.ModelClasses.Model_Sport_Info;
import com.ModelClasses.Model_User_info;
import com.briggnright.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Frag_My_favourite_sports extends Fragment
{
    //Declare Variables
    View rootView;
    ListView list_sport_list;
    ArrayList<Model_Sport_Info> arraylist_sport_info;
    Model_Sport_Info model_sport_info;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_favourite_sports, container, false);//inflate layout on fragment Home Fragment
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("              Favourite Sports");
        setUI();
        arraylist_sport_info =new ArrayList<Model_Sport_Info>();

            model_sport_info=new Model_Sport_Info();
            model_sport_info.setSport_Image(R.drawable.soccer);
            model_sport_info.setSport_Name("Soccer");
            arraylist_sport_info.add(model_sport_info);

            model_sport_info=new Model_Sport_Info();
            model_sport_info.setSport_Image(R.drawable.basketball);
            model_sport_info.setSport_Name("Basketball");
            arraylist_sport_info.add(model_sport_info);

            model_sport_info=new Model_Sport_Info();
            model_sport_info.setSport_Image(R.drawable.baseball);
            model_sport_info.setSport_Name("Baseball");
            arraylist_sport_info.add(model_sport_info);

            model_sport_info=new Model_Sport_Info();
            model_sport_info.setSport_Image(R.drawable.football);
            model_sport_info.setSport_Name("Football");
            arraylist_sport_info.add(model_sport_info);

            model_sport_info=new Model_Sport_Info();
            model_sport_info.setSport_Image(R.drawable.hockey);
            model_sport_info.setSport_Name("Hockey");
            arraylist_sport_info.add(model_sport_info);

            list_sport_list.setAdapter(new Favourite_sports_List_Adapter(getActivity(), arraylist_sport_info));

        return rootView;
    }
    private void setUI()
    {
        list_sport_list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_favourite_sports);

    }


}
```

My Adapter class is like,

```
package com.AdapterClasses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.ModelClasses.Model_Sport_Info;
import com.briggnright.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Favourite_sports_List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Model_Sport_Info> arraylist_sports_info;
    Typeface myTypeface;

    public Favourite_sports_List_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_Sport_Info> arraylist_sports_info){
        this.context = context;
        this.arraylist_sports_info = arraylist_sports_info;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist_sports_info.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {      
        return arraylist_sports_info.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView txt_sport_name,txt_select_team;
        Button btn_checked_unchecked;
        RelativeLayout btn_select_team;
        ImageView img_sports_image;



    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

    {
        View v=convertView;
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/robotoregular.ttf");

        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_favourite_sport, parent,
                    false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_sport_name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_item_favourute_sports_text);
            holder.txt_sport_name.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            holder.img_sports_image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_list_item_favourite_sports_image);
            holder.btn_checked_unchecked=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_list_item_favourite_sports_checked);
//          holder.btn_select_team=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.rel_btn_list_item_favourite_sports_select_team);
            holder.txt_select_team=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_btn_list_item_favourite_sports_select_team);
            holder.txt_select_team.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            //Set info.
            holder.txt_sport_name.setText(arraylist_sports_info.get(position).getSport_Name()+"");
            holder.img_sports_image.setImageResource(arraylist_sports_info.get(position).getSport_Image());
            holder.btn_checked_unchecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
//                  holder.btn_checked_unchecked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
//                  holder.btn_select_team.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_only_rounded_edges);
//                  holder.txt_select_team.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#192131"));

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }


        public  void fragmentSet(int id,Fragment fragment)//Fragment replacing method.
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentmanager= ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(id, fragment).commit();

        }

    }
```

It give followin Error,

```
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254): Process: com.briggnright, PID: 8254
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2265)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-18 12:47:49.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8254):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In get view method return v;
instead of return convertView;

Comment: Does the suggestion in my post work or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the inflated view. `convertView` is null in your case

Change this

```
return convertView;
```

to

```
return v;
```